# Re-utilize try-catch with closure and multiple params

Tags: groovy

Trying to achieve the following:

1. Since the same try-catch block is used so often, abstract it to a Closure
2. Pass logging information as well: Class and Method name

I have the following so far but just can't get it to work, some hints would be greatly appreciated.. not a groovy expert

```
@Test
void eventListingJsonResponse() {


    assertionErrorClosure {

        EventListingTest.class, "eventListingJsonResponse" ->

        given()
            .header("accessTokenKey",accessTokenKey)
            .header("accessTokenSecret", accessTokenSecret)
        .expect()
                .statusCode(200)
            .and()
                .body("events.any {it.containsKey('clientid')}", is(true))
        .when()
            .get(basePath)
    }
}

def assertionErrorClosure(Closure closure) {

    def claz = 'c'
    def meth = 'm'

    logInfo(this.getClass(), "-- Start testing of $meth with clientId: $clientId --\n")

    try {
        closure()
    } catch (AssertionError e) {
        logWarning(claz, "Error testing $meth: \n\n$e")
    }
}
```

Is this possible ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there, you have to pass the closure arguments and the closure itself to the `assertionErrorClosure` function separately like this:

```
assertionErrorClosure(this.class, "eventListingJsonResponse") {

    clazz, methodName ->

    print "hello world from class: ${clazz} and method: ${methodName}"

    //your test code here

}

def assertionErrorClosure(Class clazz, String methodName, Closure closure) {

    print("" + clazz + "-- Start testing of $methodName --\n")

    try {
        closure(clazz, methodName)
    } catch (AssertionError e) {
        logWarning(claz, "Error testing $methodName: \n\n$e")
    }
}
```

You can replace the `print()` with your loggers and `this.class` with `EventListingTest.class`.